# I have doubt in which statistic test should I use

Tags: statistical-significance, genetics

I have three groups of flies A, B and C which are genetically different, to which I submit two different treatments: NO SUGAR and SUGAR. I would like to see if statistically one of the groups of flies (A, B or C) behave differently to one or to the two treatments.

I thought of using the one-way ANOVA but I am using two treatments, not one … I also thought of using the multiple t test but that isn´t exactly what I need because I need to compare the three groups of flies and not two by two ….

Comment: You are on the right track.  Look up 2-way ANOVA because you have two factors.  One of your factors has two levels (NO SUGAR vs SUGAR) and the other factor has three levels (A, B, and C).  This could be called a 2x3 factorial design.